# What is the idiomatic way to create a fixed size std::array from a fixed size std::span?

Tags: c++, c++20, stdarray, std-span

I am trying to create a `std::array<uint8_t,N>` from a `std::span<uint8_t,N>` but I cannot find a way to do so without `memcpy`, `std::copy`, or `std::ranges::copy` which don't protect me against wrong specification of destination array size.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <span>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  constexpr size_t N = 10;
  std::array<uint8_t, N> original;
  std::span span(original); // of type std::span<uint8,N>

  std::array copy1(span);                               // does not work
  std::array<uint8_t, N> copy2(span);                   // does not work
  std::array<uint8_t, N> copy3(begin(span), end(span)); // does not work


  // ugly stuff that works, but does not protect me if I specify wrong array size
  constexpr size_t M{N - 1}; //oops, leads to array overflow
  std::array<uint8_t, M> copy4;
  std::copy(begin(span), end(span), copy4.begin());
  std::ranges::copy(span, copy4.begin());

  return 0;
}
```

What is the idiomatic way to do this in modern C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on @Jarod42's answer, we can make a few improvements:

```cpp
#include <span>
#include <array>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

// 1. constrain this function to copy-constructible types
template <std::copy_constructible T, std::size_t N>
    requires (N != std::dynamic_extent)
// 2. handle spans of const/volatile T correctly
std::array<std::remove_cv_t<T>, N> to_array(std::span<T, N> s)
// 3. add conditional noexcept specification
    noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<T>)
{
    // add type alias so we don't repeat the return type
    using result_type = decltype(to_array(s));
    if constexpr (std::is_trivial_v<T>) {
        // 4. avoid unnecessary instantiations of std::index_sequence etc.
        //    in the cases where we can copy with no overhead (should be fairly common)
        result_type result;
        // note: we cannot simply use std::memcpy here because it would not
        //       correctly handle volatile T
        std::ranges::copy(s, result.begin());
        return result;
    }
    // TODO: consider using std::ranges::copy for all default-constructible
    //       and copyable types, because the following results in huge assembly output
    else {
        // if 4. is not applicable, we still have to use @Jarod42's solution
        return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
            return result_type{s[Is]...};
        }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
    }
}
```

If you wanted to further reduce the assembly size, you could use the following condition instead:

```cpp
std::is_default_constructible_v<T> && std::is_copy_assignable_v<T>
```

If you fear that there is overhead from `std::ranges::copy` over initialization, you can use `std::is_trivially_default_constructible_v<T>`, possibly with `std::ranges::uninitialized_copy`, which should mitigate this.

Comment: @ildjarn you're right, the type needs to be trivial, not just trivially copyable so that the optimization is possible. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 6):

> but I cannot find a way to do so without `memcpy`, `std::copy`, or
> `std::ranges::copy` which don't protect me against wrong specification
> of destination array size.

If a `span` has a *static* extent, its `size()` can be implemented as a constant expression, which works on current mainstream compilers:

```
std::array<uint8_t, span.size()> copy4;
std::ranges::copy(span, copy4.begin());
```

Or you can get the size value through its static member constant `extent` (like `std::array<uint8_t, span.extent>`), which is guaranteed to work.

Comment: What would be the way to get the extent from the type of the `span` variable? Like for the array I can write `std::tuple_size_v<decltype(original)>`, how do I retrieve the extent from `decltype(span)`?

Comment: @phinz `span` has a public static member constant named `extent`, which is the value of the template parameter `Extent`, so you can `decltype(span)::extent` or just `span.extent`.

Comment: Using `span.extent` might be problematic though, as it might be `std::dynamic_extent`...

Answer (score 4):

You might wrap it in a function:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
std::array<T, N> to_array(std::span</*const*/ T, N> s)
requires (N != std::dynamic_extent)
{
    return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
        return std::array<T, N>{{s[Is]...}};
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

Note: I avoid `std::copy` as it requires to have default constructor for `T` (for the initial array).

Comment: Could return `std::array<std::remove_const_t<T>, N>`

Comment: I chose this as the answer because in the general case it is indeed important that the default constructor is not used.

Comment: Something I don't like is the fact that initialization is explicit per element such that for large `N` a lot of code is generated. I would prefer a method which internally exploits the linear arrangement of elements and that uses a loop internally, this solution seems to me like an unrolled loop. But it seems the standard library is lacking a better answer for my question. Do you think compilers can write the unrolled loop as normal loop again to avoid excessive code for large `N`?

Comment: @phinz you're right that the assembly output is huge, for example for https://godbolt.org/z/cYb9rfGqa. I've provided an alternative solution which fixes this for trivially copyable types, and which could cover more cases.