# How to initialize a data member of an array type in a class template's member initializer list？

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14, member-initialization, index-sequence

For example, I have a class called `Vector` that represents a vector and a class called `Integer` that represents an integer.

```cpp
class Integer{
public:
   Integer(int v):value_(v){};
private:
   int value_;
};
template<uint32_t Dim>
class Vector{
public:
     Vector(int v[Dim]) 
      ://How to initialize each element of the value_ array here?
     {
     }
private:
     Integer value_[Dim];
}
```

Since `Integer` does not have a default constructor, you must initialize each element of the `value_` array in the member initializer list of `Vector`. However, since the length of the array is a template parameter, you cannot directly use something like `value_{v[0], v[1], v[2]}` to initialize the value_ array.
I'm using c++14.

Comment: Is this is a practical question, or a theoretical one? In practice, `Integer` would just have a default constructor. You *could* live without out, using `std::index_sequence` and delegating constructors, but you're just making things harder for yourself for no good reason.

Comment: I designed a class similar to this Integer in my actual work. The reason I didn't provide a default constructor is to force users to provide meaningful initialization data when creating objects of this class, ensuring that each created object is valid.

Comment: not sure: may be you could use std::copy on a range get from calling std::begin and std::end on your array?

Comment: Perhaps you could use `std::array` instead of a plain array, both as a member and as a parameter? Then the initialization will just work, but you won't be able to pass a sub-array of a larger array.

Comment: Another thing to think about: is `Integer` movable? If yes, are moved-from instances invalid? And if yes, it the lack of default constructor worth it, if invalid instances are still possible to create?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've said, if the size was known, you could write `value_{v[0], v[1], v[2]}` directly.

#### Solution A - [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence)

Given that the size isn't known, you can write something like:

```cpp
private:
template <std::size_t... I>
Vector(const int(&v)[N], std::index_sequence<I...>)
  : value_{v[I]...} {}

public:
Vector(const int(&v)[Dims])
  : Vector(v, std::make_index_sequence<Dims>{}) {}
```

*Note: this uses a reference to an array so that the size is checked.*

The pack expansion `v[I]...` acts like `v[0], v[1], ...` for an arbitrary amount `Dims` of indices (as specified when creating the index sequence with `std::make_index_sequence`.

#### Solution B - [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

However, since your `Vector` class only contains an array member, it would be much easier to just have no constructor and rely on aggregate initialization instead.
If you had no constructor, you could write `Vector<3>{1, 2, 3}` as well.

#### Solution C - [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

You could also have a single constructor:

```cpp
// note: value_ should be std::array as well
Vector(const std::array<int, Dims>& content) : value_{content} {}
```

`std::array` has value semantics, and trivializes the problem because you can just copy/move it around like any other object.

#### Further solutions

See [What is the idiomatic way to create a fixed size std::array from a fixed size std::span?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76790161/5740428). This question is about C++20, but the solutions there are applicable to older versions as well.